# open gvim in the same location on windows 7

Tags: windows, vim, windows-7

I've been trying to get into gvim for a week now but one thing that drives me up the wall is that each new time I open it, it appears a little to the right lower then before.

Is there way to stop this from happening?

I'm using windows 7 and gvim 7.2.

Answer (score 0):

add "*winpos x y*" to your _gvimrc file. x y is the top left corner of the GVim window in pixels. For example:

```
set columns=140
set lines=56
winpos 20 50
```

Habi